# Rails 4 - Model Schema Logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am struggling to get a jump to develop the logic for some models.

Specifically, I am trying to carryout a concept with Twilio Messaging as shown in this article:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-have-users-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-twilio

Honestly, I don't even know where to start, model-wise, to store this information and how limit users to specific numbers with specific conversations.  Any ideas or concepts to get me started would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you find an open-source project similar to the one you are trying to model on Github, and just read their code. Great way to see how others do similar things.

Comment: Twilio employee here. There are two resources that I think might be useful for you. First, conversation tracking using cookies: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms/tracking-conversations. Second, integrating Twilio with Rails 4: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html.